# Vector notion question

Tags: vectors

I'm learning vectors and there's two notions which I don't distinguish :

Is the orientation of a vector (determined by the angle it has) the same thing as the direction of a vector ???

thank you

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339142/whats-the-difference-between-direction-sense-and-orientation) could help.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, the vectors $v$ and $-v$ have the same direction but the opposite orientation.